# ¿Por qué se usa "naranjas" para negar con rotundidad?

Tags: etimología, historia, comida, interjecciones, compuestos

En el DLE se recoge la interjección [**naranjas**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QEs8tdX#M2DwA9D):

> 1. interj. U. para denotar asombro, extrañeza, desahogo, etc.
> 2. interj. U. para negar o rechazar algo con rotundidad.

seguida de las variantes:

> **naranjas chinas**, o **naranjas de la China**
>   1. locs. interjs. **naranjas**

¿Cómo se originó esa interjección, cuyo significado aparentemente no tiene ninguna relación con las acepciones habituales de la palabra?

Comment: por el "na" de naranjas? 
en ingles se usa el "bananas" por el doble "na"

Comment: A juzgar por el uso argentino *naranjas* remite a *nada*. Sólo lo usamos en la frase fija *"No pasa naranja"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A juzgar por definiciones antiguas de la interjección, parece que simplemente el hecho de que la palabra empezara por *n* ya la conviertía en candidata para equivaler a *no*, al igual que otras palabras similares como *nones*.

La voz se recoge desde 1925, cuando decía lo siguiente:

> **¡Naranjas!** interj. con que se denota asombro, extrañeza, desahogo, etc. Sirve también para negar, caso en que equivale a **nones**.

La voz *nones* ya se usaba en el siglo XVIII como negación, de hecho el *Terreros y Pando* de 1787 dice que se usaba "entre Jitanos" y era "lo mismo que decir no". Y muy cerca en el tiempo encuentro este caso de *naranjas* como interjección:

> *Marqués:
>
>   ¡Qué delicia! Estas bondades
>
>   sobrepasan mi esperanza.
>
>   Permita usted que a esos pies
>
>   (Arrodíllase.)
>
>   yo me prosterne, me abata,
>
>   me confunda. ¡Ah, qué sonrisa
>
>   tan insinuante!*
>
> *Tío Pedro:
>
>   (Saliendo de repente, y quedándose suspenso al ver al Marqués.)
>
>   ¡Naranjas!
>
>   ¡Con qué devoción está!*
>
> Tomás de Iriarte, "La señorita malcriada", 1788 (España).

E incluso uno anterior:

> *Cirujano:
>
>   Usted atienda.
>
>   (Lee.) "Y después, sin que se enfríe,
>
>   se le echará una docena
>
>   de sanguijuelas."*
>
> *Cochero:
>
>   ¡Naranjas!*
>
> Ramón de la Cruz, "El Cochero y monsiur Corneta", c 1767 (España).

La verdad es que en ninguno de los dos casos propuestos la interjección se usa como negación, sino que tienen una clara intención de expresar asombro. Es posible, por tanto, que en su origen no influyera la *n* inicial, sino que fuese al revés, que la interjección de asombro se convirtiera en negación dado este hecho. Lo cual deja a la pregunta inicial sin respuesta.

Por tratar de recabar la mayor cantidad de pistas posibles, he notado en la hemeroteca de la BNE que la palabra "naranja" se usa sobre todo a partir de 1759, siendo muy escasa su aparición en publicaciones antes de ese año (y la mayoría de casos antes de ese año son de la expresión "media naranja"). No es que la palabra no se usara antes, pero al parecer a partir de 1759 empezó a ser noticia, entiendo que por su importancia en el comercio, como [este recorte](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002574940&page=1&lang=es) que cita las naranjas en la lista de las "preciosas mercancías" de las Américas.

Por esas fechas debió de crearse la expresión, que fue recogida al poco en obras de teatro, que reflejaban el habla del momento. No encuentro ningún caso de la interjección antes de la década de 1760.

Comment: Góngora (1561-1627) en su "Ándeme yo caliente y ríase la gente" cita la naranjada:  Traten otros del gobierno del mundo y sus monarquías, mientras gobiernan mis días mantequillas y pan tierno; y las mañanas de invierno **naranjada** y aguardiente, y ríase la gente.  --- Y en el CORDE aparecen casos de siglos anteriores ...